# Почему перекрывается индексатор базового класса?

Tags: c#, .net

Всем привет! Столкнулся с непонятным для меня поведением индексаторов. Для примера такой код:

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        B b = new B();

        int index = 2;
        Console.WriteLine(b[index]);

        double value = 2.0;
        Console.WriteLine(b[value]);
    }
}

abstract class A
{
    protected List<string> _values = new List<string>()
    {
      "0.25",
      "0.5",
      "0.75",
      "1.0",
      "1.5",
      "2.0",
      "2.5"
    };

    public string this[int index] => _values[index];
}

class B : A
{
    public string this[double value] => _values
        .FirstOrDefault(item => value < Convert.ToDouble(item, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture))
        ?? "*ERROR*";
}
```

В методе Main при обоих обращениях по индексу происходит обращение к индексатору, принимающему значение double (который в классе B) и игнорируется индексатор, принимающий значение int (который в базовом классе A). Если же перенести индексатор из A в B:

```
abstract class A
{
    protected List<string> _values = new List<string>()
    {
      "0.25",
      "0.5",
      "0.75",
      "1.0",
      "1.5",
      "2.0",
      "2.5"
    };        
}

class B : A
{
    public string this[double value] => _values
        .FirstOrDefault(item => value < Convert.ToDouble(item, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture))
        ?? "*ERROR*";

    public string this[int index] => _values[index];
}
```

То обращение к индексаторам происходит корректно по типам: для double и int вызываются соответствующие типу индексаторы.
В чём причина такого поведения?

P.S. Оказывается, с перегруженными методами та же ситуация. Проверил на таком коде:

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        B b = new B();

        int index = 2;
        Console.WriteLine(b.GetValue(index));

        double value = 2.0;
        Console.WriteLine(b.GetValue(value));
    }
}

abstract class A
{
    protected List<string> _values = new List<string>()
    {
      "0.25",
      "0.5",
      "0.75",
      "1.0",
      "1.5",
      "2.0",
      "2.5"
    };

    public string GetValue(int index) => _values[index];
}

class B : A
{
    public string GetValue(double value) => _values
        .FirstOrDefault(item => value < Convert.ToDouble(item, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture))
        ?? "*ERROR*";        
}
```

Что же это за мистика такая?

Comment: здесь уже был вопрос про то как выбирается метод в зависимости от параметром. Суть в том, что `int` в `double` может конвертироваться, поэтому вызывается ближайший метод описанный в классе. Если ты поменяешь местами методы - в базовом классе `double` параметр, в наследнике `int` - то будет работать так как ты ожидал

Comment: Да, мне понятен такой ход мыслей. То есть, ищется "лучший" метод для типа переданного параметра. Т.к. int может неявно преобразовываться в double, а в классе как раз есть метод, принимающий double, то он и используется. Мне странно только, что не выполняется поиск более подходящих методов по базовым классам. Если метод с параметром int переместить в производный класс, то с типом int становится сразу "лучше". Но если он в базовом классе - то это делает его "хуже" даже несмотря на то, что по сигнатуре он подходит лучше. Это нелогично, на мой взгляд, но буду учитывать в будущем. Спасибо за ответ!

Comment: Формально, нет смысла лезть в базовый класс, если есть подходящий метод в текущем классе

Comment: Действительно, это всё объясняет, спасибо! Вообще, плохая была идея использовать индексатор с типом double. Заменил его на метод, теперь работает как надо :)